# Redirect main website to /blog

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, redirect, nginx

Hello I have a website with image links like this:

```
<img src="/flower.jpg"/>
```

I have a task to change the website path from `www.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/blog`. as `www.domain.com` will be used for a different site.

I am handling the redirect with nginx so `www.domain.com/blog` loads up the new website but the assets and images are not loading obviously because the links like `<img src="/flower.jpg"/>` are searching for images at :

```
www.domain.com/flower.jpg
```

whereas the image is available at

```
www.domain.com/blog/flower.jpg
```

Now I dont want to change the paths everywhere in the code. whats the best way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I just re-read your question and realised you've already moved your image files.

If you're using Apache you can try setting up a virtual host for you /blog directory, and set DocumentRoot in the config?

Otherwise I'm afraid you've got a lot of path adjusting to do in your code.

Comment: there is something called as base href in html , can that help ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) or [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

The `location`-method:

```
location ~ /[^/]*.jpg {
  root /your/images/directory;
}
```

The `rewrite`-method:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /blog/$1.jpg;
```